# How to send line of terminal output to variable?

Tags: c++, terminal, output

In c++, I want to send a command to the terminal(`system()`) and then send whatever output the terminal shows into a variable, but I don't know how. I'm aware of the `std::getline()` function, but I'm not sure that would do the trick. If you know a way to complete this task, please let me know. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Tricky. `system` is too stupid for what you want because it doesn't give you access to the console output of the program run by `system`. In a POSIX system you'd use `popen`. Not sure what you use in Windows.  Once you have the console output, you parse it and grab the data you need. I recommend adding your target operating system so people can point you at the right functions and a sample of the console output you need parsed so people can help out with that as well. At the moment this question cannot be fully answered.

Comment: `popen()` plus a little magic. It's all about pipes.